# What to do if I upvoted by mistake?

Tags: support, voting

I upvoted an answer by mistake. I wanted to downvoted it. I get "You can't change your upvote without edit the answer" or something like this.

How do I deal with it?

Comment: If you react quickly enough (a few minutes) you can change your vote. After that it is locked. If you have edit permissions (> 2000 points I believe) you can make a meaningless edit and change your vote. If not you have to wait that someone else edits the answer before you can change your vote.

Comment: @mbloch meaningless edits are generally discouraged

Answer (score 2):

Forget about it. A single vote on the wrong direction — whatever direction that may be — will probably not affect anyone very much. It happens; move on.

If you really want to change (or rescind) your vote, though, you'll be able to do so once the post you voted on has been edited. So keep checking back on it for edits and then you can vote again. Alternatively, if there's something that you see you can really improve in the post such that editing it is worthwhile (honestly, not just to allow you to vote), go ahead and edit.

Comment: Something does feel a bit wrong about upvoting (albeit accidentally), then editing the post and downvoting after your own edit. As if the post was originally good but then you edited it and now it's bad.

Comment: If your edit fixes the problem, it might deserve your upvote at that point. Or you could remove your vote entirely. @daniel